# Spring MVC @PathVariable to catch only first level

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot app that includes some controllers and static resources. I need to be able to have a controller that matches:

> /hello

and

> /hello/

but not

> /wonder/hello

(or anything else). It seems that when I use the following mapping:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{slug}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String mapping(@PathVariable("slug") String slug)
```

it does a "catch-all" whereas I only need it to catch the first level. This causes issues with the static resource mapping.

Comment: Did you test your controller? It perfectly fits to your requirement.

Comment: It does not work if you have static resources in your project. They don't get picked up.

Comment: I did not down vote it..I guess it's better to config your resource handler to serve static resources with a prefix like `/static`.

Answer (score 0):

use @RequestMapping("/hello") in the starting of controller

Comment: I need wild path mapping.

Comment: what exactly the wild path mapping ?

Comment: This is actually the correct answer given your question - but do you mean you actually need to map "/hello" and /hello/**"?  (if so, the second example would be more intuitive if you provided more of the URL)

Comment: Thanks but pls read the question again: I need a "catch-all" for the first level of a URL /{xxx}/

Comment: in that case you can use two @RequestMapping("/hello") as class level and another one at method level that's you are using.